# How to delete CMD instructions so I can run program in IDE console (Python)?

Tags: python, eclipse, cmd, ide

I have a code (below) which run only if it executed from CMD. I need to modify it and it *must* run in the IDE console (Eclipse).

When I trying to do that in Eclipse, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\workspace\TF\TF\predict_2.py", line 138, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What it need to be done ?

I am reading something about `__main__` and `sys.argv` but I don't understand so much...

```
"""Predict a handwritten integer (MNIST expert).

Script requires
1) saved model (model2.ckpt file) in the same location as the script is run from.
(requried a model created in the MNIST expert tutorial)
2) one argument (png file location of a handwritten integer)

Documentation at:
http://niektemme.com/ @@to do
"""

#import modules
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import os
from datetime import datetime

def predictint(imvalue):
    """
    This function returns the predicted integer.
    The input is the pixel values from the imageprepare() function.
    """

    # Define the model (same as when creating the model file)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

    def weight_variable(shape):
      initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
      return tf.Variable(initial)

    def bias_variable(shape):
      initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
      return tf.Variable(initial)

    def conv2d(x, W):
      return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

    def max_pool_2x2(x):
      return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')   

    W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

    W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

    W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

    y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    """
    Load the model2.ckpt file
    file is stored in the same directory as this python script is started
    Use the model to predict the integer. Integer is returend as list.

    Based on the documentatoin at
    https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/variables/index.html
    """
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        saver.restore(sess, "model2.ckpt")
        #print ("Model restored.")

        prediction=tf.argmax(y_conv,1)

        return prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: [imvalue],keep_prob: 1.0}, session=sess)

def imageprepare(argv):
    """
    This function returns the pixel values.
    The input is a png file location.
    """
    im = Image.open(argv).convert('L')
    width = float(im.size[0])
    height = float(im.size[1])
    newImage = Image.new('L', (28, 28), (255)) #creates white canvas of 28x28 pixels

    if width > height: #check which dimension is bigger
        #Width is bigger. Width becomes 20 pixels.
        nheight = int(round((20.0/width*height),0)) #resize height according to ratio width
        if (nheight == 0): #rare case but minimum is 1 pixel
            nheigth = 1  
        # resize and sharpen
        img = im.resize((20,nheight), Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        wtop = int(round(((28 - nheight)/2),0)) #caculate horizontal pozition
        newImage.paste(img, (4, wtop)) #paste resized image on white canvas
    else:
        #Height is bigger. Heigth becomes 20 pixels. 
        nwidth = int(round((20.0/height*width),0)) #resize width according to ratio height
        if (nwidth == 0): #rare case but minimum is 1 pixel
            nwidth = 1
         # resize and sharpen
        img = im.resize((nwidth,20), Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        wleft = int(round(((28 - nwidth)/2),0)) #caculate vertical pozition
        newImage.paste(img, (wleft, 4)) #paste resized image on white canvas

    #newImage.save("sample.png")

    tv = list(newImage.getdata()) #get pixel values

    #normalize pixels to 0 and 1. 0 is pure white, 1 is pure black.
    tva = [ (255-x)*1.0/255.0 for x in tv] 
    return tva
    #print(tva)

def main(argv):
    """
    Main function.
    """
    imvalue = imageprepare(argv)
    predint = predictint(imvalue)
    print (predint[0]) #first value in list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: You probably aren't passing an argument. Without you giving the command you used to generate the error it's not easy to say what you've done wrong. It's also not very clear what you are trying to do. Do you mean how do you run this code from an IDE terminal? Or how do you turn this code into a standalone script? Please edit more information in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I am trying to do is to execute this code from the IDE terminal, not from CMD. The error I receive is just above.

Comment: I can see the error but not what you typed in to get the error. Please edit your question with the full information. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to see how to ask a question to get the best help.

Comment: The error happen when I try to execute the program in Eclipse. If I run it in CMD (with the right argv) it works well. Nothing need to be typed in Eclipse, just run it and you will see. My question is: the code can be modified in a way that it can be executed in IDE or I have to do it only in CMD ?

Comment: Ah so you don't mean the IDE terminal then. You just mean running the script from the IDE. It's because the script is expecting you to pass an argument with the image file. Just remove the the argument requirement and pass the image inside the code

Comment: Do you know how to do it ? What to remove ?

Comment: Try passing a path string to an image instead of `sys.argv[1]` on the bottom line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149207/discussion-between-bluetrack-and-jcooke).

Answer (score 0):

Like @JCooke said, the code must be modified in the `main(sys.argv[1])` by deleting/insert "other".

In my case, I had to view the processing of an image in the IDE console. In CMD I had to give an argument which had to be the path to the image itself.
In the code I changed `sys.argv[1]` with the path of the image.